# SQL subquery with comparison

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

On a Rails (5.2) app with PostgreSQL I have 2 tables: `Item` and `ItemPrice` where an `item` has many `item_prices`.

**Table `Item`**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | poetry book |
| 2 | programming book |

**Table `ItemPrice`**

| id | item_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 |
| 4 | 1 | 6 |
| 5 | 2 | 22 |

I am trying to select all the items for which the last price (price of the last offer price attached to it) is smaller than the one before it

So in this example, my request should only return item 1  because 6 < 8, and not item 2 because 22 > 20

I tried various combinations of Active records and SQL subqueries that would allow me to compare the last  price with the second to last price but failed so far.

ex `Item.all.joins(:item_prices).where('EXISTS(SELECT price FROM item_prices ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 as last_price WHERE (SELECT price FROM item_prices ...` can't work it out..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows using `ROW_NUMBER` and `LAG`:

`LAG` to get the previous row based on a condition

```
WITH ranked_items AS (
SELECT m.*, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn,
  LAG(price,1) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY id ) previous_price
  FROM ItemPrice AS m
)
SELECT it.*
FROM ranked_items itp 
inner join Item it on it.id = itp.item_id
WHERE rn = 1 and price < previous_price
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XQ1QGe4d)

Comment: clearly a few notions I need to get familiar with to perform advanced queries as this one.  Thanks a lot, and for the demo!